# How get emojis to work with mysql 5.7?

Tags: mysql, emoji

Im trying to get emojis to work in with my mysql 5.7 and .asp pages.

I have set the db and tables to use the right collections etc.

In the mysql my.ini file I have this.

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-server=utf8mb4
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

And if I in mysql workbench writes this.

```
SHOW VARIABLES
WHERE Variable_name
LIKE 'character\_set\_%'
OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
```

Then I get this

```
'character_set_client', 'utf8'
'character_set_connection', 'utf8'
'character_set_database', 'utf8mb4'
'character_set_filesystem', 'binary'
'character_set_results', 'utf8'
'character_set_server', 'utf8mb4'
'character_set_system', 'utf8'
'collation_connection', 'utf8_general_ci'
'collation_database', 'utf8mb4_general_ci'
'collation_server', 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
```

So client, connection, result are still showing as utf-8.

But if I write this global one then they are utf-8mb4!?

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' 
OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';

'character_set_client', 'utf8mb4'
'character_set_connection', 'utf8mb4'
'character_set_database', 'utf8mb4'
'character_set_filesystem', 'binary'
'character_set_results', 'utf8mb4'
'character_set_server', 'utf8mb4'
'character_set_system', 'utf8'
'collation_connection', 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
'collation_database', 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
'collation_server', 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
```

Then I connect with this to the db to my pages.

```
strConn = "driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver};server=localhost;uid=test;pwd=test;database=test;option=3;charset=utf8mb4;" 
    set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open strConn
```

And in my .asp pages I set the charset like this at the top of the page.

```
Response.charset="utf-8"
```

Then in mysql workbench I have run the

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4
```

to be able to insert an emoji. (I don´t know why I have to use SET NAMES utf8mb4 before I can insert an emoji?)

I have done all this and I still get a ? instead of an emoji.?

So what am I missing?
Any input really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does it help to add `;charset=utf8mb4` to your connection string?

Comment: Hi Bradley, thanks, but I already have that. I have read everything I could find, and this is the only thing you have to do everybody says, but still it is not working?

Comment: Assuming the character is stored correctly in MySQL Server (can you verify this with MySQL Workbench?) there's potentially a conversion from server→ODBC Driver, then from ASP→HTML. The replacement of an emoji character with `?` could be happening in either/both of those layers, so we'd need more details to track this down; I'd recommend adding diagnostics to verify whether the string in your ASP code does indeed contain the emoji.

Comment: Hi I have tested to store the emoji both as a string &1F60A; and as an image inserted directly from the workbench emojis and none works. If I use &1F60A; then that is displayed on the webpage and if I use an image then I get the ? Maybe the problem is in the ODBC connection? But what to look for?

Comment: could this problem be solved? i do have problems to save emojis in my table in a utf8mb4 column.

Comment: B.Kemmer. I got it working in the end. I had to use MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver for it to work. It did´t work with 5.2 or 5.3